# Change color of a specific word generated by script

Tags: javascript, scripts

I'm trying to adapt a code to change the color of a single word, but I have no idea how.

The original code is

```
crypt_single_getPar = eval('(' + httpGet("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/" +
crypt_single_base_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1] + "-" + crypt_single_target_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1]) + ')');
```

and

```
if (crypt_single_getPar.success != false) {
if (crypt_single_getPar.ticker.price > 1)
    crypt_single_price = Math.round(crypt_single_getPar.ticker.price * 100) / 100;
else
    crypt_single_price = crypt_single_getPar.ticker.price

var crypt_single_text_style = '<font style="color:#cc0000;"><b>&darr;</b></font>';

if (crypt_single_getPar.ticker.change >= 0) {
    crypt_single_text_style = '<font style="color:#009900;"><b>&uarr;</b></font>';
}

document.write('\
<div class="cryptonatorwidget" style="border-radius:4px;padding:10px;' + crypt_single_style + '">\
<div><font style="font-size:90%;">' + crypt_single_base_currency + '</font>\
<b>' + crypt_single_price + '</b> ' + crypt_single_target_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1] +'\
</div>');
```

The result is

[image: original]

And I'm trying to change the color like this

[image: desired]

I tried to achieve the result

```
document.write('\
<div class="cryptonatorwidget" style="border-radius:4px;padding:10px;' + crypt_single_style + '">\
<div><font style="font-size:90%;">' + crypt_single_base_currency + '</font>\
<b>' + crypt_single_price + '</b> ' + <font style="font-color:#2ED7A2;">' + crypt_single_target_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1] + '</font>\
</div>');
```

But then all disappeared in the web page.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Never use a code that calls `eval`. 2. How is this specific to wordpress?

Comment: Thanks for the eval tip.

I'll move to Stack Overflow as requested.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of

```
<font style="font-color:#2ED7A2;">' + crypt_single_target_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1] + '</font>
```

try

```
<span style="color:#2ED7A2;">' + crypt_single_target_currency.match(/.*?\(([0-9a-z]+)\)/i)[1] + '</span>
```

the font tag isn't supported in html 5 and you were calling "font-color" instead of just "color"

Comment: Hi. Didn't work. I'll keep trying. Thanks ^^

Comment: show me the code output...